# Random rows based on unique values

Tags: python, dataframe, unique

I want to get 2 random but distinct person IDs from a DF and put it into another DF

| Person_id | post | active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 567 | yes | inactive |
| 678 | yes | active |
| 567 | no | inactive |
| 689 | yes | active |
| 680 | yes | inactive |
| 689 | no | active |

```
df['person_id'].sample(n=100, random_state=1)
```

This code is NOT getting the unique person_id values and only putting that column in a df. I need to get a number of that specific column's unique values and put it into a df with all other columns as well.

```
df.person_id.sample(n=100, random_state=1).groupby('person_id')
```

I tried this as well but it creates a weird object

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [567, 678, 567, 689, 680, 689],
                   'post': ['yes', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'no'],
                   'active': ['inactive', 'active', 'inactive', 'active', 'inactive', 'active']})
```

To select two random unique person ids:

```
selected = df['person_id'].drop_duplicates().sample(n=2)
```

To create data frame with all rows for selected person ids:

```
df[df['person_id'].isin(selected)]
```